# Animating across state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I have a menu which has a sub-menu for each item in it. Whenever the item is clicked, the sub-menu slides in. The title of the menu also changes when this happens. I want to animate the title change so that there is a smooth fade-in fade-out effect. Consider following code snippet inside render method of the React component:

```js
render() {
   // other code
   return(
     <div className={`title ${this.state.subMenu.isOpen ? `open` : ''}`}>
        <div>{this.state.heading}</div> // this heading changes when the sub-menu opens/renders
     </div>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```css
@keyframes fade {
    0%,100% { opacity: 1 }
    50% { opacity: 0 }
}

.title {
   background : black;
   color : white;
}

.title.open {
   animation: fade 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that `open` class is applied after the component has re-rendered on state change, and so the animation starts after the new heading has been rendered. This gives a flickering effect. However, I want the animation to start as soon as the state change begins. I looked at [react-transition-group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) for this, but it doesn't seem to provide the required solution for this case. In below code, `CSSTransition` requires  mounting and un-mounting of its children from the DOM. While here, only the value (heading) of the DOM element changes.

```html
<CSSTransition
    in={this.state.subMenu.isOpen}
    timeout={500}
    classNames="open">
    <div className={`title ${subMenu.isOpen ? `open` : ''}`}>
        <div>{this.state.heading}</div> // heading changes when the sub-menu opens
    </div>
</CSSTransition>
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`, read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate).

However, if you cannot use that, you could use `componentDidUpdate` if you want to have side effects after any states changed.

Comment: I am trying this out, but I am not sure how to add class from within `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`? Maybe I can use a `Ref` and then use that to set the css class on the heading. But not sure `Ref` can be used to set css class.

Comment: You can write a variable which holds your classes, and then re-write it inside. Also, you could use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm package